# Fetch HTML From URL in Python

Tags: python, html, url

I am trying to read the `HTML` contents of a `URL` with `Python`. To fetch the `HTML` contents of a `URL`, would I use the module `wget`, `urllib` or a different module entirely?

After Answers: 
I will use the `urllib` module since that comes with the default Python 2.7 build, and I can't download external modules from this computer.

List of Modules That Fetch URL Contents:

```
Wget
Beautiful Soup
Urllib
Requests
```

Comment: Have you tried `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Yes. There are multiple choices (add requests to the list) and you can use any of them.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? There are a lot of questions and answers on this site about this topic. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @MooingRawr I will upload some code soon. I'll try my 1st attempt at fetching html elements from a URL with `wget` and post it once I'm done.

Comment: @345243lkj I have not tried `BeautifulSoup`, but I will look into it, and decide if it's the module I should use for this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample to get you started with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
if resp.ok:
    print (resp.text)
else:
    print ("Boo! {}".format(resp.status_code))
    print (resp.text)
```

Comment: This is the simplest. Replace `print resp.text` with `print(resp.text)` if you're using Python3.x

Comment: Aside: http://httpbin.org is an excellent resource for testing clients.

Comment: Thanks, @345243lkj - I fixed the sample and the comment.